# Slow text preprocessing

Tags: java, performance

anyone can help why my program is running slow to process 650 documents , it takes 130 minutes, and how to make this program have better performance to preprocessing
here the main class****

```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, BiffException, Exception {
    ArrayList<dataset> dokumen = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> term = new ArrayList<>();
    TA_baru t = new TA_baru();
    Himpunan_metoda_pembobotan hmp;
    dokumen = t.bacatxt(dokumen);//reading dokumen

    term = t.doktermlist(dokumen);//split it into term 
    hmp = new Himpunan_metoda_pembobotan(dokumen, term);
    hmp.tulistf();
    hmp.tulisidf();

}

public ArrayList<String> doktermlist(ArrayList<dataset> tt) throws IOException, BiffException {
    ArrayList<String> tmp = new ArrayList<>();
    Set<String> a = new HashSet<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < tt.size(); i++) {
        //tt.get(i).ubah_term();
        tmp = tt.get(i).getTerm();

        for (int j = 0; j < tmp.size(); j++) {
            a.add(tmp.get(j));
        }
    }

    //tmp.clear();
    tmp = new ArrayList<String>(a);
    return tmp;
}

public ArrayList<dataset> bacatxt(ArrayList<dataset> x) throws IOException, BiffException {
    x.clear();
    File folder = new File("C:\\Users\\burhan\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\TA_baru\\data");
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
    dataset y;
    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
        File file = listOfFiles[i];
        if (file.isFile() && file.getName().endsWith(".txt")) {
            String content = FileUtils.readFileToString(file);
            y = new dataset(file.getName(), content);
            x.add(y);
        }

    }
    return x;
}
```

and here class himpunan_metoda pembobotan

```
public class Himpunan_metoda_pembobotan {

ArrayList<dataset> dokumen = new ArrayList<>(), positif = new ArrayList<>(), negatif = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> term = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Nilai> nabcd = new ArrayList<>();
double a, b, c, d;

public Himpunan_metoda_pembobotan(ArrayList<dataset> dok, ArrayList<String> term) {
    dokumen = dok;
    this.term = term;
    for (int i = 0; i < dok.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < term.size(); j++) {
            abcd(term.get(j), dokumen.get(i));
        }//this loop for assign value to nabcd 
        System.out.println(i);
    }

}

public int jumlah_kategori() {
    Set setkategori = new HashSet();
    for (int i = 0; i < dokumen.size(); i++) {
        setkategori.add(dokumen.get(i).getKategori());
    }
    return setkategori.size();
}

public int jumlah_dokumen_terdapat_term(String x, ArrayList<dataset> y) {
    int a = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < y.size(); i++) {
        if (y.get(i).getTeks().contains(x)) {
            a++;
        }
    }
    return a;
}

public void clear() {
    positif.clear();
    negatif.clear();
    a = 0;
    b = 0;
    c = 0;
    d = 0;
}
public void carinilaiabcd(String tem,String kategori ){
    for (int i = 0; i < nabcd.size(); i++) {
        if (nabcd.get(i).getKata().equals(tem)&&nabcd.get(i).getKategori().equals(kategori)) {
            a=nabcd.get(i).getA();
            b=nabcd.get(i).getB();
            c=nabcd.get(i).getC();
            d=nabcd.get(i).getD();
        }
    }
}
public void abcd(String x, dataset y) {
    Nilai n;
    clear(); //this looping make run slow, and how the solution for this problem
    for (int i = 0; i < dokumen.size(); i++) {
        if (dokumen.get(i).getKategori().equals(y.getKategori())) {
            positif.add(dokumen.get(i));
        } else {
            negatif.add(dokumen.get(i));
        }
    } //separate beetween negative and positif category
    for (int i = 0; i < positif.size(); i++) {
        if (!positif.get(i).carikata(x)) {
            a++;
        }
        if (positif.get(i).carikata(x)) {
            b++;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < negatif.size(); i++) {
        if (negatif.get(i).carikata(x)) {
            c++;
        }
        if (!negatif.get(i).carikata(x)) {
            d++;
        }
    }//assign value a, b, c,d to search value idf, tf,
    n = new Nilai(a, b, c, d, x, y.getKategori()); //assign nilai
    n.setIdf(idf(n));
    n.setTf(tf(x, y));
    nabcd.add(n); //add nilai into arraylist
}

public double tf(String term, dataset data) {
    return data.jumlah_term(term);
}
public double itf(String term, dataset data) {
    double x=0;
    x=1-(1/(1+tf(term, data)));
    return x;
}
public double rf(String term, Nilai n) {
    //abcd(term, data);
    double x = 0;
    if (n.getC() < 1) {
        x = Math.log(2 + (n.b / 1));

    } else if (n.getC() > 0) {
        x = Math.log(2 + (n.b / n.c));

    }
    return x;
}
public double tfrf(String term, Nilai n,dataset data) {
    //abcd(term, data);
    double x = 0;
    x=tf(term, data)*rf(term, n);
    return x;
}
public double idf(Nilai n) {


    double x;
    x = Math.log10(dokumen.size() / (n.b + n.c));
    return x;
}

public double tf_idf(String term, dataset data,Nilai n) {

    double x = 0;
    x = tf(term, data) * idf(n);
    return x;
}

public double x2(String term, dataset data) {
    abcd(term, data);
    double x;
    x = dokumen.size() * (((a * b) - (c * d)) / ((a + d) * (b + c) * (a + b) * (c + d)));
    return x;
}

public double OR(String term, dataset data) {
    abcd(term, data);
    double x;
    x = Math.log((b * d) / (a * b));
    return x;
}

public double IG(String term, dataset data) {
    abcd(term, data);
    double x;
    double n = dokumen.size();
    x = ((-(b + a) / n) * Math.log((b + a) / n)) - ((((c + d) / n) * Math.log((c + d) / n)))
            + ((b / n) * Math.log(b / (b + c))) + ((c / n) * Math.log(c / (b + c)))
            + ((a / n) * Math.log(a / (a + d))) + ((d / n) * Math.log(d / (d + a)));
    return x;
}

public double ngl(String term, dataset data) {
    abcd(term, data);
    double g;
    g = ((Math.sqrt(dokumen.size()) * ((a * d) - (b * c)))) / (Math.sqrt((b + c) * (a + d) * positif.size() * negatif.size()));
    return g;
}

public double gss(String term, dataset data) {
    abcd(term, data);
    double g;
    g = (a * d) - (b * c);
    return g;
}

public double iqf(String term, dataset data) {
    abcd(term, data);
    double g;
    g = Math.log(dokumen.size() / (b + c));
    return g;
}

public double qf(String term, dataset data) {
    abcd(term, data);
    double g;
    g = Math.log(b + 1);
    return g;
}

public double vrf(String term, dataset data) {
    abcd(term, data);
    double g;
    g = Math.log(b + 1) / Math.log(a + 1);
    return g;
}

private double dia(String term, ArrayList<String> dok) {
    double z, n = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < dok.size(); i++) {

        String temp = dok.get(i).toLowerCase();
        if (temp.contains(term)) {
            n++;
        }
    }
    z = n / (double) dok.size();
    return z;
}



public void tulisidf() {
    try {
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("hasil_iidf.csv");
        try (FileWriter out = new FileWriter(new File("hasil_iidf.csv"))) {
            out.write("dokumen_data");
            for (int i = 0; i < term.size(); i++) {
                out.write("," + term.get(i));
            }
            out.write("," + "Class");
            out.write("\n");
            int gap=term.size();
            int n=0,j;
            System.out.println(nabcd.size());
            System.out.println(term.size());
            System.out.println(nabcd.get(0).getIdf());
            for (int i = 0; i < dokumen.size(); i++) {
                out.write("dokumen_" + i);
                for ( j=n; j < gap; j++) {
                    out.write("," + nabcd.get(j).getIdf());

                }
                n=gap;
                gap=gap+term.size();
                //n=j+1;
                out.write("," + dokumen.get(i).getKategori());
                out.write("\n");
            }
            out.close();
        }
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void tulistf() { //to write tf into csv
    try {
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("hasil_tf.csv");
        try (FileWriter out = new FileWriter(new File("hasil_tf.csv"))) {
            out.write("dokumen_data");
            for (int i = 0; i < term.size(); i++) {
                out.write("," + term.get(i));
            }
            out.write("," + "Class");
            out.write("\n");
            int gap=term.size();
            int n=0,j;
            System.out.println(nabcd.size());
            System.out.println(term.size());
            System.out.println(nabcd.get(0).getIdf());
            for (int i = 0; i < dokumen.size(); i++) {
                out.write("dokumen_" + i);
                for ( j=n; j < gap; j++) {
                    out.write("," + nabcd.get(j).getTf());
                }
                n=gap;
                gap=gap+term.size();
                //n=j+1;
                out.write("," + dokumen.get(i).getKategori());
                out.write("\n");
            }
            out.close();
        }
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: *What* is slow? Have you compared the time of the reading from disk vs. the actual processing?

Comment: First glance: Where you marked the code, you iterate the whole list, categorizing it and saving the results to two new lists which you again iterate. My suggestion would be: Try to put this into one iteration. But do not expect too much, there may be more things to improve.

Comment: i think looping for nabcd make slow down performance ,,,probably need improvements to make program more faster
i compared with using database, and it more faster

Comment: could you please tell us what kind of analysis you did on your sw to verify its performance? 650 documents: same size and complexity for all the documents? if you use the same document, 10 times, 100 times, 650 times, the process time increase geometrically? the documents are hosted on your pc?

Comment: @BurhanudinYusufUtomo You absolutely have to use english for naming classes, methods, variables, comments in your code, especially if it has to be read by someone except you. For you Himpunan_metoda_pembobotan has great meaning, I have no idea what that's supposed to do.